# Where can I find information on swift actions?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, actions

I found that the rules in Player's Handbook do not cover swift actions. A friend suggested to look in Oriental Adventures, since that is the book that introduced them properly. I did not find anything. The D20 SRD has little information on swift actions.

Can any one inform me if one can use a swift action and then a full round action, what is the general description of swift actions and the page of the book they were introduced?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[From the d20 SRD:](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#swiftActions)

> A swift action consumes a very small amount of time, but represents a larger expenditure of effort and energy than a free action. You can perform one swift action per turn without affecting your ability to perform other actions. In that regard, a swift action is like a free action. However, you can perform only a single swift action per turn, regardless of what other actions you take. You can take a swift action any time you would normally be allowed to take a free action. Swift actions usually involve spellcasting or the activation of magic items; many characters (especially those who don't cast spells) never have an opportunity to take a swift action.
>
> Casting a quickened spell is a swift action. In addition, casting any spell with a casting time of 1 swift action is a swift action.
>
> Casting a spell with a casting time of 1 swift action does not provoke attacks of opportunity.

Answer (score 2):

From [DandD Wiki](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD%3aSwift_Actions)

> A swift action consumes a very small amount of time, but represents a
>   larger expenditure of effort and energy than a free action. You can
>   perform one swift action per turn without affecting your ability to
>   perform other actions.

You can do a swift and a full round action. All a swift action is is an immediate action that you can only perform one of in a turn.