# Warblade maneuver recovery

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle

Can a warblade recover their maneuvers using a swift action and a full-round attack?

Typically [the manual](https://web.archive.org/web/20200120044903/http://archive.wizards.com:80/default.asp?x=dnd/ex/20060802a&page=2) says:

> You can recover all expended maneuvers with a single swift action, which must be immediately followed in the same round with a melee attack or using a standard action to do nothing else in the round (such as executing a quick, harmless flourish with your weapon).

Can you also use a swift and a full-round?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To recover you need to do **both** of the following:

- A swift action, **and**
- **One** of the following:

  - Attempt a melee attack (**any** melee attack, such as the standard-action attack, part of a full-attack, even an attack of opportunity though there is a risk you won’t get one)
  - **Or** spend a standard action to flourish

So yes, you can make a full-attack as part of your warblade recovery.

Answer (score 1):

In any given round you are given one of three options:

1. Full round action
2. Move action and a standard action
3. Two Move actions.

You also get an **unlimited*** number of free actions, and a single swift **or** immediate action.

> **Free action**: You can perform one or more free actions while taking another action normally. However, there are reasonable limits on what you can really do for free.
>
> **Swift action**: A swift action consumes a very small amount of time, but represents a larger expenditure of effort and energy than a free action. You can perform only a single swift action per turn.

Immediate actions are swift actions that are not on your own turn.

> Using an immediate action on your turn is the same as using a swift action, and counts as your swift action for that turn. (effectively, using an immediate action before your turn is equivalent to using your swift action for the coming turn).

So, **yes**, they can make a swift action, and then a full round action, with that full round action being a full attack.

Comment: included general turn based rules, because asker seemed uncertain of these rules.

Answer (score 0):

Oh! I vote you can because that little word "or" separating melee attack and standard action.

But maybe not?

"A full-round action consumes all your effort during a round. The only movement you can take during a full-round action is a 5-foot step before, during, or after the action. You can also perform free actions (see below).

Some full-round actions do not allow you to take a 5-foot step.

Some full-round actions can be taken as standard actions, but only in situations when you are limited to performing only a standard action during your round. The descriptions of specific actions, below, detail which actions allow this option."

Comment: You can take a swift action and a "full-round" action in the same round. Refer to [this answer](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/12562/14988)